# WP confused by pointers to struct

Tags: frama-c

I'm struggling to have WP verify the postcondition of a function that swaps 2 structs.

```c
typedef struct { int x; int y; } pair;

/*@
    requires \valid({p, q});
    assigns *p, *q;
    ensures *p == \old(*q);
    ensures *q == \old(*p);
*/
void swap(pair *p, pair *q);
```

If I add a few assertions in the body, WP verifies them all except the last one, which is the same as the first one!

```c
void swap(pair *p, pair *q) {
    pair tmp = *p;

    *p = *q;
    //@ assert *p == \at(*q, Pre);

    *q = tmp;
    //@ assert *q == \at(*p, Pre);

    // WP is not sure anymore!
    //@ assert *p == \at(*q, Pre);
}
```

This happens with Phosphorus-20170501, on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Note that WP succeeds if the function swaps 2 pointers to int, or 2 elements of an array of struct, instead of 2 pointers to struct.

So, what's the matter with pointers to struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify that `p` and `q` cannot point to the same structure, so WP cannot guess that the last assignment cannot modify `(*p)`.

You can do what you want by adding a precondition:

```
requires \separated(p, q);
```

Comment: That works, but I still wonder how WP verifies the array version `void swap(pair *a, int i, int j)`, which has the same problem.

Comment: In the array version, you just have one pointer, so you cannot have a separation problem, can you?

Comment: If `i` equals `j` then `a[i]` and  `a[j]` are the same object. Also, WP has no problem with pointers to `int`...

Comment: Yes, but even in this case, the properties are true. In the first case, `(*p)` and `(*q)` may overlap without being equal (imagine some dirty casts).

Comment: That explains why WP validates the array version. Since 2 pointers to `int` can overlap too, shouldn't WP reject the `void swap(int*, int*)` version?